# my function based valdiation doesnot work , it doesnt enter the method! it validates using default way

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

THE ERROR I get !

> ["Datetime has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: %, Y,
>   -, %, m, -, %, d,  , %, H, :, %, M."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqSc8.png)

This is the serializer.py file

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from sponsorapp.models import Sponsormodel
    from datetime import datetime
    import datetime as dt

 class SponsorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        offer_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', input_formats='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        sponsorship_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', input_formats='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

        class Meta:
            model = Sponsormodel
            fields = ('sponsorship_date' , 'offername' , 'offer_date')

        def validate_sponsorship_date(self , value):
            data = self.get_initial()
            offerdate = data.get('offer_date')
            offerdate = datetime.strptime('offerdate','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
            sponsorshipdate = value
            sponsorshipdate =datetime.strptime('sponsorshipdate' , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

            if(sponsorshipdate > offerdate):
                raise ValidationError("Check the dates")
            return value
```

Model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Sponsormodel(models.Model):
    sponsorship_date = models.DateTimeField()
    offername = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    offer_date = models.DateTimeField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.offername
```

Where am i wrong ? , i mean there is no error , the function based validation does not work .

Comment: `sponsorshipdate =datetime.strptime('sponsorshipdate' , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` you're passing sponsorshipdate as a string rather than a variable. I don't know if that's everything behind your error, but certainly that part will not work.

Comment: Also, from your screenshot, it seems as though you're specifying dates as day-month-year but then telling `datetime` that it's in the format year-month-day.

Comment: ya ! i mean where and what do i need to change ! ?? im a beginner in django rest ! and python
what can i put instead if datetime ?? i mean the documentation has only these options

Comment: Did you try and change the two things I have already pointed out? Did that help? I'm not prepared to do full debugging on your code. You cannot convert the string `'sponsorshipdate'` to a datetime, so remove the quotes. Same with `'offerdate'`. Ensure you're configured to parse dates in the way that they are entered on the site. If that doesn't solve everything, you need to do some debugging yourself and, finally, edit your question if there's a specific error you cannot overcome. This is too general currently.

Comment: ok ! great ! thanks for the help ! i have to learn debugging and setting up debugger to sublime .!